# XML parser removes processing instruction close delimiter's question mark

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've encountered the following unexpected behaviour with the `xml` parser used by Python 3.4's BeautifulSoup 4. When parsing an xml stylesheet, the question mark in the closing delimiter disappears:

Input:

```
BeautifulSoup('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet href="myStyleSheet.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>','xml')
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="myStyleSheet.xsl" type="text/xsl">
```

Notice how `type="text/xsl"?>` changed to `type="text/xsl">`.

Also, the example found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/#introduction) breaks in the same way.

Is this intentional? Should I report a bug? Is there any way to prevent this other than inserting a question mark in the correct place afterwards?

Comment: I don't know what the BeautifulSoup specification says, but removing the question mark is correct if you're generating HTML, and incorrect if you're generating XML.

Comment: The XML parser should specifically handle XML. Funny thing is, the HMTL parsers I tried (`html.parser` and `lxml`) _don't_ remove the question mark. (But they do other things I don't want)

Comment: xml.etree.ElementTree does the exact same thing as does lxml.etree

Answer (score 3):

From the changelog for version 4.5.0 of BeautifulSoup released 7/19/2016:

"* Corrected handling of XML processing instructions. [bug=1504393]"